# How can I read 2 nodes from this SOAP response - and can I do with it SimpleXML

Tags: php, soap, curl, simplexml

I am familiar with SimpleXML and am now receiving a SOAP response from a client. I have tried reading as many examples as I can from reading it with SimpleXML, but I just cannot get mine to work! Can some one please show me a line of PHP that reads the DESCRIPTION node in the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetPoliciesResponse xmlns="http://www.abraxas-uk.com/Abraxas/InsuranceWebsite/InsWebService/">
      <GetPoliciesResult>
        <Policies xmlns="">
          <Policy>
            <Description>Off-Pad Warranty</Description>
            <Plan />
          </Policy>
        </Policies>
      </GetPoliciesResult>
    </GetPoliciesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am pulling my hair out!

Comment: Can you paste your code using SimpleXML? Maybe we could make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC using SimpleXML with a document containing multiples XML namespaces is a mess.

You could use DOM (ie. without XPath) :

```
<?php

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetPoliciesResponse xmlns="http://www.abraxas-uk.com/Abraxas/InsuranceWebsite/InsWebService/">
      <GetPoliciesResult>
        <Policies xmlns="">
          <Policy>
            <Description>Off-Pad Warranty</Description>
            <Plan />
          </Policy>
        </Policies>
      </GetPoliciesResult>
    </GetPoliciesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$doc = DOMDocument::loadXml($xml);

$desc = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Description')->item(0)->textContent;

echo $desc;
```

With a more complex case, you may have to use XPath instead of `DOMNode::getElementsByTagName()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

For your convenience, you could switch between the two worlds (DOM / Simplexml) :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-import-dom.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dom-import-simplexml.php

Comment: this is perfect - it's just a one off reply i need to grab two values from!!! thanks :)